# Not able to get a new `instance` from a `class`

Tags: angular5

Here is my detail class:

```
export class Details {
  model = {
    "name":"",
    "city":"",
    "pin" : ""
  }
}
```

getting a instance for various page :

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Details } from './details';

@Injectable()
export class SharedDataService {

  constructor(){}

  object1 = new Details().model; //updates this data to object 2
  object2 = new Details().model; //it is not empty, updated with object 1

  sharedData = new BehaviorSubject( this.object1  );
  sharedObserver = this.sharedData.asObservable();

  sharedDataHello = new BehaviorSubject( this.object2  );
  sharedObserverHello = this.sharedData.asObservable();

  updateSharedData(object){
    this.sharedData.next(object);
  }

  updateSharedDataHello(object){
    this.sharedDataHello.next(object);
  }


}
```

In `object2` - I am looking for empty object. but the `object1` values are assigned to `object2` - how to prevent this?

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/shared-data) - navigate to `hello` page and see the console.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the service as follow it works fine:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Details } from './details';

@Injectable()
export class SharedDataService {

  object1 = new Details().model;
  object2 = new Details().model;

  constructor(){
    console.log( '1', this.object1);
    console.log( '2', this.object2);
  }

  sharedData = new BehaviorSubject( this.object1  );
  sharedObserver = this.sharedData.asObservable();

  sharedDataHello = new BehaviorSubject( this.object2  );
  sharedObserverHello = this.sharedDataHello.asObservable();

  updateSharedData(object){
    this.sharedData.next(object);
  }

  updateSharedDataHello(object){
    this.sharedDataHello.next(object);
  }

}
```